# Compound Interest Calculator

Tags: c#

C# beginner, trying to create a program where a user enters an amount, years, and rate and then calculates the total amount. The rate will be divided by 100 to get the decimal value and the years will be multiplied by 12 to get the monthly rate.

Here is the code:

```
class Program
{  
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CompoundClass program = new CompoundClass();

        Console.Write("Please enter the initial balance for your account: ");
        double balance = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.Write("Please enter the annual interest rate: ");
        double interestRate = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

        program.Rate(interestRate);

        Console.Write("How many years will you acrue interest? ");
        double anualAmount = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

        program.Years(anualAmount);

        Console.WriteLine($"Your balance after {anualAmount} years is {totalAmount:C}\n");

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

class CompoundClass
{
    public double rate;
    public double yearlyRate;
    public double balance;

    public void Rate(double interestRate)
    {
        if (interestRate > 0)
        {
           rate = interestRate / 100;
        }
    }

    public void Years(double anualAmount)
    {
        if (anualAmount > 0)
        {
            yearlyRate = anualAmount * 12;
        }
    }

    public void addMethod(double totalAmount)
    {
        for (int i = 1; i < yearlyRate + 1; i++)
        {
            totalAmount = balance * Math.Pow(1 + rate / yearlyRate, yearlyRate * i);
        }
    }
}
```

I keep getting the error:

> CS0103The name 'totalAmount' does not exist in the current context.

I don't know if any information is being pulled correctly and stored/calculated.

Comment: Whether you can access a variable depends on the variable's scope and access level.

Comment: You haven't defined a variable named `totalAmount` anywhere, except as an argument to the `addMethod` method, which is never called.

Comment: So I have to add double totalAmount; as well as use it in the addMethod? Why didn't I have to do that for the annualAmount or interestRate? totalAmount should be the total amount calculated.

Comment: It seems to me that if you're trying to get a "total amount", then you should create a property or method that returns that value. Maybe the easiest would be to rename `addMethod` to `GetTotalAmount`, have it return a `double` instead of `void` (it doesn't appear to need any arguments for input), and then do the calculation and return the value from that method. Then the caller could do something like `var totalAmount = program.GetTotalAmount();`. There are other problems in general, but since you're just starting I suppose they could be ignored for now.

Comment: Also, some of the variable names are deceptive. `yearlyRate` is not a rate, it's the number of months to use for calculating the total. And the loop you're using is just reassigning a variable over and over again, but not doing any compounding of interest.

Comment: Thank you so much for the tips. I am very much new to C#. As I'm sure you could tell by my code......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are having that error because the 'totalAmount' variable can only be accessed inside CompoundClass. This is because it is created with a default access modifier private. 
You created an object for CompoundClass

```
CompoundClass program = new CompoundClass();
```

You have accessed the methods using the object. Regarding your question for annualAmount or interestRate, you didn't access the variables from CompoundClass, you have just passed them from Program class. However you can still access rate, yearlyRate, and balance through the object like program.rate and so on. This is because you have declared them as public.

```
public double rate;
public double yearlyRate;
public double balance;
```

If you want to access totalAmount as well, please declare that as public.

```
program.addMethod(balance);
Console.WriteLine($"Your balance after {anualAmount} years is {program.totalAmount:C}\n");
```

Comment: Oh okay! I implemented the change and I get this error: CS1061  C# does not contain a definition for and no accessible extension method accepting a first argument of type could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: You need to add a public variable: `(public double TotalAmount { get; set; }`


`public void AddMethod(double balance) // Preferred casing
        {            
            for (int i = 1; i < yearlyRate + 1; i++)
            {
                TotalAmount = balance * Math.Pow(1 + rate / yearlyRate, yearlyRate * i);
            }             
        }`
In the program Class you will need 

`program.AddMethod(balance);  
            Console.WriteLine($"Your balance after {anualAmount} years is {program.TotalAmount:C}\n");`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you did not declare the variable 'totalAmount' within main, you declared it in 'addMethod', as a result you are trying to use the variable out of it's scope.

You also did not call the function yet, thus I would recommend creating the output variable 'totalAmount' in main, and then assign it the output of the function 'addMethod' (Thus call the function).

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to print out (from `program`) the value of a variable that you have not declared (`totalAmount` from within `program`).

Since it is looking like you want to calculate `totalAmount` you want to change your `addMethod` to return the calculated amount instead of accepting `totalAmount` as a parameter.

For example in `program` do

```
double totalAmount = addMethod();
Console.WriteLine($"Your balance after {anualAmount} years is {totalAmount:C}\n");
```

And implement `addMethod` to return the value:

```
public void addMethod()
{
    double calculatedTotalAmount = 0;

    for (int i = 1; i < yearlyRate + 1; i++)
    {
        calculatedTotalAmount = balance * Math.Pow(1 + rate / yearlyRate, yearlyRate * i);
    }

    return calculatedTotalAmount;
}
```

Effectively, you are assigning the value calculated within the scope of the method to `totalAmount`, which is declated in the outer scope.

Comment: Thank you! When I debugged it, the total amount came back as 0. Is this a calculation error?

Comment: Looks like a logic error. I copied your code somewhat, mostly to highlight the difference in variable scoping and how you might return back a value, and as such may have copied your logic error. Perhaps step through with a debugger...